# Mojolicious: redirecting in a /subdir/subdir/some.cgi won't yield an absolute url

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am trying to redirect in the file `/subdir/subdir/some.cgi` which calls the following method:

```
$self->redirect_to("/anothersubdir/some.html");
```

However, the above call will redirect to `/subdir/subdir/some.cgi/anothersubdir/some.html` instead. So how do I really make it redirect to `/anothersubdir/some.html`?

Comment: Where is `some.html` in relation to `some.cgi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you must provide an absolute path to `redirect_to`.

Why ? Because [redirect_to](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller#redirect_to) says *...same arguments as* [url_for](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller#url_for), which generates that url unless it is absolute. The docs aren't too explicit, but the source is.

So you could construct a new Mojo::URL object and give it to `redirect_to`:

```
my $url = Mojo::URL->new->base($self->req->url->base->clone)->base->userinfo(undef);
$url = $url->path('/anothersubdir/some.html');
$self->redirect_to( $url );
```

Or copy `redirect_to` and modify it to not use `url_for`

```
sub redirect_raw {
  my $self = shift;

  # Don't override 3xx status
  my $res = $self->res;
#~   $res->headers->location($self->url_for(@_)->to_abs);
  $res->headers->location();
  return $self->rendered($res->is_status_class(300) ? () : 302);
}
```